# How to convert a fixed height/width-fixed layout to elastic?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fixed, fluid-layout

I used the same software used here http://us.gn.bartal.org/ to create a fixed width/height treemap in HTML + CSS.

I would like to make it elastic by having a JavaScript function to convert all pixels absolute positions and sizes to percentages.

How would you suggest to proceed? Is there some jQuery/Prototype/Dojo magic that I can exploit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your basic process would be something like this:

- Identify the elements that need resizing
- Write some JQuery to find the sizes of those elements
- Calculate the percentages (or other values)
- Make the adjustments
- Subscribe to all relevant resize events
- Recalculate the sizes on each resize event

Comment: I already wrote a solution which work pretty much like this. However, I would prefer to convert them in actual percentage-size elements, so that they will naturally adapt to resizing.

Comment: @phretor: Then, all you need to do is step 3 from my answer.

Comment: Thank you John. I hope height: X%; is cross-browser :)